# Wrong user name or password [28000-202] when trying to start/stop H2 in server mode from the shell

Tags: h2

I upgraded recently to the new [Version 2.0.202 (2021-11-25) of H2](https://h2database.com/html/main.html).
I have a shell script, which I wrote while using the Version 1.4.200 (14.10.2019 **?**), in which I stop and start a H2-Server using:

```
java -cp h2*.jar org.h2.tools.Server -tcpPort 9092 -tcpShutdown tcp://11.333.444.111:9092 -tcpShutdownForce </dev/null &>/dev/null &>>$WORKING_DIR/logs/h2_servers.log
```

After the upgrade I am getting a **wrong username or password** Exception:

> Exception in thread "main"
> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: Falscher
> Benutzername oder Passwort Wrong user name or password [28000-202]

In the *.h2.server.properties* I have no username or password set.
Is this an issue?
If not what for user name and password to use and where are they set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug.
In the earlier versions it was possible to start and stop a **H2-Server** without providing a value for **-tcpPassword**.
Using [Version 2.0.202 (2021-11-25)](https://h2database.com/html/main.html) it's possible, as with older versions, to start a H2-Server without providing a value for **-tcpPassword** like so:

```
java -cp h2*.jar org.h2.tools.Server -tcp -tcpAllowOthers -tcpPort 9092 -web -webPort 8082
```

The problem is to stop the H2-Server. Using older versions it was possible to do it so:

```
java -cp h2*.jar org.h2.tools.Server -tcpPort 9092 -tcpShutdown tcp://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9092 -tcpShutdownForce
```

In the [Version 2.0.202](https://h2database.com/html/main.html) I get:

```
java -cp h2*.jar org.h2.tools.Server -tcpPort 9092 -tcpShutdown tcp://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9092 -tcpShutdownForce
Shutting down TCP Server at tcp://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9092
Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: 
Wrong user name or password [28000-202]
```

Which password to provide as I didn't use any?
I opened an [issue](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/3289).

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the same password when you start a TCP server and when you stop it with additional

```
-tcpPassword some_password
```

arguments in both commands.

If your server is configured to accept remote connections, you need to choose a some secure password.

Comment: @[Evgenij Ryazanov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11731987/evgenij-ryazanov): please read my question carefully. I have no password and I ran the script over 100 times without any problem and again **without any password***

Comment: It isn't possible in H2 2.0 **due to security reasons**. This operation is disallowed if password wasn't set explicitly.

Comment: Hi [Evgenij Ryazanov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11731987/evgenij-ryazanov) Is it mentioned in the documentation?

Comment: https://h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#using_server